# Distribution of imputed values and multivariate analysis

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, data-imputation, partial-least-squares

Below you'll find two plots showing the Q-Q plot (top) and histogram (bottom) of two variables. The aim is to use them, together with others, with sPLS and other multivariate methods for regression purposes. The data were imputed and log-transformed by other people.

[image]
[image]

Although I do not know much about imputation methods, these plots both seem quite odd. At the moment I do not have access to the raw, original data, so I cannot check whether this is the result of the imputation step, as I suspect. Do you believe that the distribution of these variables may cause problems with downstream analyses? It just so happens that many of the variables with this kind of behavior are also the most *important* ones.

Comment: What behaviour specifically are you concerned about? The first plot looks like there are many observations with the smallest possible value and in the second the values may have been rounded, but neither of those are necessarily problems. Also remember that in general the distribution of the independent variables ($X$) isn't crucial for regression purposes. Do you have domain-specific knowledge that suggests these distributions would be implausible?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. To be honest, they just look "artificial", if you will. I am worried this behavior could cause problems later on. The other problem is that some of these variables are actually response variables. I do not have much domain knowledge at the moment, but looking into it.

Comment: They don't look that unusual to me, but you'll have to judge that for yourself. If the first plot is a response variable then you'll probably need to use some sort of "zero-inflated" model to accommodate the extra observations at the minimum. For the second, maybe try to re-make the histogram with the bin boundaries set so that each of the horizontal bands in the qqplot are in their own bin? (Or, more crudely, just decrease the number of bins) That would get rid of the empty spots in the histogram and perhaps look more acceptable. (Second might be better modeled as a Gamma distribution?)